# Calculating in closed form another digamma alternating series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is there any clever way of finish it fastly?

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{n+1} \left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{5}{8}+\frac{3 n}{8}\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{3 n}{8}\right)\right)$$

Maybe using series representation of digamma or other ways you might like to share. Or is it possible to finish it by series manipulation only (as a distinct matter I'm interested in)?

*Supplementary question*: prove that

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{n+1} \left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{5}{8}+\frac{9 n}{32}\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{9 n}{32}\right)\right)$$

$$=\frac{64}{9} \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right) \tan ^{-1}\left(\cot \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)-\csc \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)\right)-\frac{32 \tan ^{-1}\left(\cot \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)-\csc \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)\right)}{3 \sqrt{3}}-2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\cot \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)-\csc \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right)-2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\cot \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+\csc \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right)-2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\left(1-\cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right) \csc \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right)+2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\cot \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+\csc \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right)-2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sec \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)-\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right)+2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sec \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right)+2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sec \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)-\tan \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right)-2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sec \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+\tan \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right)+4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\cot \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)-\csc \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)+4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\cot \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+\csc \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)-4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sec \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)-\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)+4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sec \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)-4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\left(1-\cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right) \csc \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)-4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\cot \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+\csc \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sec \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)-\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sec \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sec \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)-\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right) \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sec \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right) \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sec \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)-\tan \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right) \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sec \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+\tan \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right) \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)-8 \pi  \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)-\frac{64}{9} \tan ^{-1}\left(\sec \left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)+\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)\right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)+\frac{32}{9} \pi  \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)+\frac{32}{9} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{9}\right) \log (2)+\frac{7 \log (2)}{9}-\frac{32}{9} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{9}\right) \log \left(2-2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)\right)-\frac{32}{9} \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right) \log \left(\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{9}\right)+1\right)+2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \log \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+1\right)-\sqrt{2} \log \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+1\right)+2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \log \left(2-2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right)-\sqrt{2} \log \left(2-2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right)+2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right) \log \left(\cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+1\right)+\sqrt{2} \log \left(\cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+1\right)-2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right) \log \left(2-2 \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right)+\sqrt{2} \log \left(2-2 \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right)-2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \log \left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+1\right)-2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right) \log \left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+1\right)-2 \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right) \log \left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+1\right)-\sqrt{2} \log \left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+1\right)-2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \log \left(2-2 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right)+2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right) \log \left(2-2 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right)+2 \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right) \log \left(2-2 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right)-\sqrt{2} \log \left(2-2 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right)+2 \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right) \log \left(\sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+1\right)+\sqrt{2} \log \left(\sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+1\right)-2 \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right) \log \left(2-2 \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right)+\sqrt{2} \log \left(2-2 \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right)+\frac{32}{9} \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right) \log \left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)+1\right)+\frac{32}{9} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{9}\right) \log \left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)+1\right)+4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\left(1-\cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right) \csc \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)-4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\cot \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+\csc \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)+4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sec \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)-\tan \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)-4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sec \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+\tan \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)+2 \log \left(\cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+1\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)+2 \log \left(2-2 \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)-2 \log \left(\sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+1\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)-2 \log \left(2-2 \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)+\frac{32}{9} \pi  \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)+\frac{64}{81} \pi  \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi }{9}\right)-4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\cot \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)-\csc \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\cot \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+\csc \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)-4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sec \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)-\tan \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)-4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sec \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+\tan \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+2 \log \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+1\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)-2 \log \left(2-2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)-2 \log \left(\sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+1\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+2 \log \left(2-2 \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)-4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\left(1-\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right) \csc \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)-4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\cot \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+\csc \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\left(1-\cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right) \csc \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\cot \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+\csc \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)-4 \log (2) \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)-2 \log \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+1\right) \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+2 \log \left(2-2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)-2 \log \left(\cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+1\right) \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)+2 \log \left(2-2 \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)-\frac{32}{9} \log (2) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)+\frac{32}{9} \log \left(2-2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)-\frac{32}{9} \log \left(\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{9}\right)+1\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)-\frac{32 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sec \left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)+\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)\right)}{3 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{64 \pi }{27 \sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: the second integral representation given in wikipedia will also work...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Integral_representations

Comment: Where do you keep coming up with these really cool questions?

Comment: @Dr.MV they simply cross my mind every day. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The series definition of the digamma function gives:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} -S&=&\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{32(-1)^n}{(8m+3n-7)(8m+3n-3)}\\&=&8\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m\geq 1}(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{8m+3n-7}-\frac{1}{8m+3n-3}\right)\\&=&8\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m\geq 1}(-1)^n\left(x^{8m+3n-8}-x^{8m+3n-4}\right)\,dx\\&=&-8\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^3\,dx}{(1+x)(1+x^4)(1-x+x^2)}\end{eqnarray*}$$
hence partial fraction decomposition gives:

> $$ S = \left(\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{2}-\frac{8}{3\sqrt{3}}\right)\pi-\frac{1}{3}\log 2. $$

About the supplementary question, with the same approach:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} S_2&=&\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{n} \left(\psi\left(\frac{5}{8}+\frac{9 n}{32}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{9 n}{32}\right)\right)\\&=& \sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{512(-1)^n}{(-28+32 m+9 n) (-12+32 m+9 n)}\\&=&32\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m\geq 1}(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{32m+9n-28}-\frac{1}{32m+9n-12}\right)\\&=&32\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m\geq 1}(-1)^n\left(x^{32m+9n-29}-x^{32m+9n-13}\right)\,dx\\&=&-32\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{12}}{1+x^9+x^{16}+x^{25}}\,dx.\end{eqnarray*}$$
Partial fraction decomposition is now just more tedious, but in any case the roots of $1+x^9+x^{16}+x^{25}$ are $32$-th or $18$-th roots of unity.

Comment: (+1) It seems it works nice. Do you think we can also finish it by series manipulation only?

Comment: @Chris'ssistheartist: I think it is possible but probably the mixed series/integral approach is the easiest way. We had to go through $24$-th roots of unity, so great skills are needed to recognize the right decomposition directly in the series.

Comment: @Chris'ssistheartist: anyway, with the same approach the series appearing in the supplementary question is easily seen to be the integral over $(0,1)$ of some rational function, so I bet your output can be greatly simplified.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so.

Comment: Your use of that wonderful trick (i.e., using the integral representation for the reciprocal terms) has worked once again to carry out this double sum.  Well done Jack!  +1

Answer (score 3):

Using the representation

$$\psi(x) = \int_0^{\infty} dt \left (\frac{e^{-t}}{t} - \frac{e^{-x t}}{1-e^{-t}} \right ) $$

and changing the order of summation and integration, we get the following integral representation of the sum:

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt \frac{e^{-t/2}}{\left ( 1+e^{-t/2} \right )\left ( 1+e^{-3 t/8} \right )} $$

Subbing $u=e^{-t/8}$, we get

$$8 \int_0^1 du \frac{u^3}{(1+u^3)(1+u^4)} $$

Comment: okkkkkkkkkk(+1) Do you think we can do it by series manipulation only?

Comment: Maybe.  But I like integrals.